# Oracle style programming in postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I want to know if oracle style object oriented programming is possible in postgresql 8.4. I have installed orafce. When I tried to create a object like so:

```
CREATE TYPE addr_obj_typ AS OBJECT (
    street          VARCHAR2(30),
    city            VARCHAR2(20),
    state           CHAR(2),
    zip             NUMBER(5));
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "object"
LINE 1: create type addr_obj_typ as object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
CREATE DOMAIN zipcode AS 
    INT CHECK(VALUE < 99999)
;

CREATE TYPE addr_obj_typ AS  (
    street  VARCHAR(30),
    city    VARCHAR(20),
    state   CHAR(2),
    zip     zipcode
);

SELECT
    CAST(('a','b','c','90210') AS addr_obj_typ);
```